# Data Analysis Platform that allows to run custom programs or scripts

Tags: networking, data-analysis

I am looking for a *self-hosted* data analysis platform that I can use to run custom programs or scripts for batch processing, and should allow to add resources over the network.
Also, it should scale so that more machines can be added. Downtimes for upscaling and for changes in configuration are perfectly fine.
The platform should be able to work with large amounts of data of arbitrary file types. Currently, we are talking about 0.5 TB of data.

I am considering implementing such a platform if there is none, but I would prefer finding a free, open-source und privacy-friendly solution to spare some time and effort.

It should allow programming/scripting in python, Java, R or bash and run on Linux (Ubuntu and Arch)